# Any iOS apps for me to talk to people just nearby?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, applications, bluetooth

I want app for iPhone or iPad, which can search for people within 100 meters (probably need to use Bluetooth), and is able to exchange information with them or talk to them directly.

Does anyone know of such an app?

Comment: If you can see them, you can go over to say hi and exchange information.

Comment: I suppose this is more for chatting/"collaborative problem solving during exams" in classrooms etc. ;)

Comment: Do you intend this app to work without needing a central matching server and shared accounts for matching people or can it include things like dating apps and geo-location apps that either leverage something like Facebook or a user account for facilitating the exchange?

Comment: yes,exactly. no central server depended. Just based on near field communication with p2p approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [Bluetooth Chat](http://itunes.apple.com/app/bluetooth-chat/id323630354?mt=8)?

> With this little app you can chat via Bluetooth with other iPhone and iPod Touch (2nd Gen) users nearby.

Customer reviews are good, so it seems to be the solution you seek.

Comment: looks like a good option - can you add more detail?

Comment: It was the first link that came up on Google. I didn't test the App.

Comment: You can still put more info on it, why might it be goo? otherwise your answer is a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with what you want to do is that the person recieving the information will need to have the app as well.

For instance you can try [Walkie Talkie](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/walkie-talkie-wifi-bluetooth/id361424957?mt=8) this lets you use Bluetooth to talk, however you cannot send not verbal information.

But for the whole purpose the iPhone has already got some of the features you require.

- Find My Friends
- iMessage
- Phone
- Email

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is a web app that does just that, it is called DistaLab and is accessible from [www.distalab.com](http://distalab.com).

It is only a web app, but I think they are going to release the app soon as it's getting quite a bit of attention.

Comment: The URL seems to have gone

Answer (score -1):

if you have iPhone you could try Messuzz!

Comment: Can you please add some details to explain what the app does and how it solves the problem stated in the question?